# Bottleneck edge in lattice of subgroups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Define the bottleneck weight of a chain of subgroups $$\operatorname{id}=H_0 < H_1 < \ldots < H_n = G$$ to be the maximum value over the indices $[H_{i+1} : H_i]$ for $i=0,\ldots , n-1.$ Let us call the *minimum* bottleneck weight over all *maximal* chains the bottleneck index $\operatorname{bot}(G).$

For example, if $G$ is cyclic, then $\operatorname{bot} (G)$ is the largest prime factor of $|G|.$ If $G=S_d$ is the symmetric group, then $\operatorname{bot} (G)\le d$: to see this, consider the chain of intransitive subgroups $$S_1 < S_2 < \cdots < S_{d-1} < S_d,$$ of bottleneck weight $d.$ If $d$ is prime, then the equality $\operatorname{bot} (S_d) = d$ holds, since one of the indices associated to any chain of subgroups must then be divisible by $d.$ When $d=4,$ however, we have $\operatorname{bot} (S_4) = 3,$ where the minimum is attained by the maximal chain $$\operatorname{id} < \mathbb{Z}_2 < \mathbb{Z}_4 < D_8 < S_4.$$

Has this notion (or at least some very close relative of it) been studied before? If so, where should one look?

Comment: $bot(S_n) = n$, with the exception of $S_4$. This is because for $n \geq 5$ every subgroup of $S_n$ has index $\geq n$.

Comment: Ah, right! I guess a common weakness of the examples I’ve given is that the maximum is always attained by a maximal subgroup…